# How to swap/change the place of ODD lines with EVEN lines using notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have sample data like this:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
line6
```

And, I want to make look like this:

```
line2
line1
line4
line3
line6
line5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^.+)(\R)(^.+)\R?`
- Replace with: `$3$2$1$2`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(^.+)       # group 1, first line
(\R)        # group 2, any kind of inebreak
(^.+)       # group 3, second line
\R?         # optional linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$3      # second line
$2      # same linebreak as original
$1      # first line
$2      # same linebreak as original
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]